# assign IP for pc vlan via dhcp server

Tags: vlan, dhcp

I made a topology that has 3 routers and 3 switches , one of the switches has VLans created on , when I setup one of the routers as a Dhcp server I face a problem that I couldn't assign IPs for PCs that belongs to another vlans than a defualt vlan (vlan 1) , although I create sub interfaces and assign their default gateway IP.

so , am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single DHCP server to serve multiple VLAN, but to do so you need to setup DHCP relay.

It must be setup on each device that act as a gateway for a VLAN.

You must also set a different DHCP pool for each VLAN.

The exact steps depends on the equipment used so its difficult to give you a more precise answer.

Comment: well , I used a single DHCP server to multiple VLAN , and I made multiple pools too , but for DHCP relay do you mean I have to setup ( ip helper ) in each sub interface ?

Comment: exactly. On Cisco it would be "ip helper-address 192.168.2.2" where 192.168.2.2 is the IP address of the DHCP server.

Comment: thanks a lot ^^ I made mistake by setup relay on the interface not on the sub interfaces .